# Transaction Log in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

For what statements DDL or DML, Transaction log is maintained and Why?

Comment: no, its just for finding answers to complex questions.

Answer (score 1):

The transaction log is used to record information on each of the transactions that have occurred.  You can use it to be able to roll back transactions, or in the case of a database recovery operation you can restore from a backup and roll forward using the recent transaction log files to re-apply any changes that have been made to the database.

Here is a [helpful article](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/understanding-the-importance-of-transaction-logs-in-sql-server/5173108) that talks about it in a bit more detail.

Comment: Yes, they should be in there as well, as they are statements.

Comment: Then why we can't rollback a truncate statement.

Comment: @Vaibhav - truncate is a meta operation - it deallocates the data pages for that table, doesn't delete them row by row.  If you trap it inside a `TRANSACTION` you CAN rollback, but you can't just recover it from the log once it's committed.

Comment: As JNK mentioned Truncate is a special case, this is for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's maintained for all DML and DDL operations, and the main purpose is to ensure the ACID properties of a database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID

However, auditing and recovery possibilities via the transaction log are possible too, but as an effect of its design which follows ACID